# easyacordion jump to desired slideNum - Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, slide

I guess you all know by now easyacordion:

http://www.madeincima.eu/blog/jquery-plugin-easy-accordion/

but i just find the documentation invisible for this..

lets say i have my acordion:

```
<div id="intro_web">
     <dt>una</dt> <dd>descripcion una</dd>    
     <dt>dos</dt> <dd>descripcion una</dd>    
     <dt>dos</dt> <dd>descripcion una</dd>    
</div>
```

and i want to have, separately, buttons to handle the accordion, like:

```
<a href="" onclick="acordion_slide(1)">una</a>
<a href="" onclick="acordion_slide(2)">dos</a>
<a href="" onclick="acordion_slide(3)">dos</a>
```

So, how would:

```
function acordion_slide(num){
      // slide and jump acordion to slidenum = num
      return false
}
```

this should look if i SET the accordion (on document ready) like this???

```
     $('#intro_web').easyAccordion({
            autoStart: true,
            slideInterval: 6000
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the mentioned plugin, but you could probably emulate a click on the desired item like this:

```
function acordion_slide(num){
    $($("#intro_web dt").get(num)).click();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a unique class to all slides. Lets say:
Slide 1 gets class="spine_1, slide 2 gets class="spine_2", etc.

Now you can easily active a particular slide.
To activate slide 5: $("dt.spine_5").activateSlide();