# How to onclick-trigger a non-native jQuery plugin's action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, javascript-framework, drupal-theming

I've installed a 3rd-party jQuery plugin (it's an accordion).  It displays on my page, and works as expected.

I want to trigger one of the plugin's actions (open a particular slide) when I click on an image on my page.

I can't seem to get the  code &/or syntax for doing that right.

The plugin I've installed is "EasyAccordion" (http://www.madeincima.eu/blog/jquery-plugin-easy-accordion/).  It's .js source is posted here: http://pastebin.com/55JB4pr2.

I'm using the plugin on a Drupal7 page.

I don't think that the specific plugin, or the fact that it's been used in Drupal, is relevant to the proper jQuery usage.

jQuery's bundled with Drupal.  I init the plugin on my page with:

```
    ( function ($) {
        Drupal.behaviors.myEasyAccordion = {
            attach: function(context,settings) {
                $('#accordion1',context).easyAccordion({
                    autoStart:     false,
                    ...
                });
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

In my markup, I have

```
    ...
    <div id="accordion1">
     ... EASYACCORDION MARKUP ...
    </div>
    ...
```

Again, with this init & markup, the accordion appears/works as expected.

On the same page, in another  I've added an image-link, i.e.,

```
    ...
    <div id="myImg">
        <a><img src="myimg.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="accordion1">
     ...  EASYACCORDION MARKUP ...
    </div>
    ...
```

I want to click on the image in the "myImg" div, and have the EasyAccordion snap to a specific open 'pane'.  The activation of a particular pane is addressed, I think, by the

```
    line #127                jQuery.fn.activateSlide = function() {
```

function, as seen at the pastebin-link I provided above.

Iiuc, I need to add code to the init function above, to tie the image-click to an action execution in the EasyAccordion.

My question is -- how?

I think I need to fire off (e.g., for slide #3),

```
    jQuery(this).activateSlide(3);
```

adding some variation of,

```
    $('#myImg').click(function () {
      ...
    });
```

to the init, attaching it to the EasyAccordion init's function().  Something like?

```
    ( function ($) {
        Drupal.behaviors.myEasyAccordion = {
            attach: function(context,settings) {
                $('#accordion1',context).easyAccordion({
                    autoStart:     false,
                    ...
                });
 ---->          $('#myImg',context).easyAccordion({ ...
 ---->          ?????????
 ---->          });
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

So far the right syntax has eluded me.  At least, I can't get the click-on-image to actually cause the specified item to 'activate' in the EasyAccordion.

These two posts,

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492258/easyacordion-jump-to-desired-slidenum-jquery-plugin
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243870/easyaccordion-jquery-plugin-callbacks
```

I think are close.  But I'm still not getting the syntax to crowbar into my Drupal.behaviors... stanza right.

Any guidance?

Comment: AFAIK the fact you are using some JS with a Drupal-generated page *does* matter. Normally you add JS code to pages or nodes with [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7). For Drupal 6 there was a [specific plugin](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui) available, but it has not been ported [yet?] to version 7.

Comment: The issue isn't one of being able to add js to the page.  The aforementioned init is added to the page with druapl_add_js.  It's added and working just fine.  The question I have is about the right way to link/activate an action.

Comment: Sure, indeed it was not an answer but a comment to the question, just in case you did not know. As sometimes the order in which you attach plugins makes a difference, and with `drupal_add_js` you should be sure the order is right. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

Adding a targetable class to each slide, so that markup's:

```
    ...
    <div id="myImg">
        <a><img src="myimg.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="accordion1">
    <dt class="slide_1" >
         ...
    <dt class="slide_2" >
         ...
    </div>
    ...
```

then, in the init,

```
    ( function ($) {
        Drupal.behaviors.myEasyAccordion = {
            attach: function(context,settings) {
                $('#accordion1',context).easyAccordion({
                    autoStart:     false,
                    ...
                });
                $('#myImg',context).click(function() {
                    $("dt.slide_1").activateSlide();
                });
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Now, a click on the img in the #myImg div opens the target slide ... here, 'slide_1', as intended.