# Drupal: How to bind a custom jQuery function to a certain AJAX response?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-ajax

I have an AJAX form which is validated by AJAX callback function. Everything is done using Drupal API. But I don't want to use standard mechanism of appending/prepending/replacing of DOM elements when callback happens. How to catch that AJAX response and react on it with my custom function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try defining a behavior. In many situations, including an AJAX request, Drupal will call to "attachBehaviors" that will trigger your behavior too:

```
Drupal.behaviors.mybehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

          console.log(context);    


  }
};
```

You must check and inspect context to know if it's the right context what are you looking for

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed. I also stumbled upon another good explanation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604687/how-to-onclick-trigger-a-non-native-jquery-plugins-action